# How can I debug the CorrelationId property in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While developing custom policies sometimes I receive error messages like the following:

```json
AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact the administrator of the site you are trying to access.
Correlation ID: fe8c8eef-3da4-4344-8928-1a95e17f23ea
Timestamp: 2021-11-24 15:11:44Z
```

What is the CorrelationId? Is it trackable?

Comment: First hit on google: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: That's the one. Suggest using the Azure AD B2C extension for VS Code as per the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Yes, correlation ID is trackable through the application insights integration in the Azure AD B2C custom policy framework. You can find the correlation ID in the Azure AD B2C sign-up or sign-in page. In your browser, select ‘View source’. The correlation appears as a comment at the top of the page. Copy the correlation ID, and then continue the ‘sign-in flow’. Use the correlation ID to observe the sign-in behavior.

•   It is just a unique global identifier value with a set format of creation between numbers, alphabets and events/activities that are taking place during that session of Azure AD B2C interaction and attached specifically to authentication requests. It is generated at every authentication hit even when authentication is successful and even when an error is encountered. It's unique to each request, not each error. However, when an error occurs, the error message contains the correlation ID that was valid for the request at the time.

•   An Admin uses the correlation ID as "breadcrumbs" to retrace a requests or processes in the Azure AD B2C logging and audit tracing to find what leads up to and causes a problem. If Azure AD B2C gets an error that it can't identify while working on that task, it posts an "Unexpected error has occurred" message, and includes the correlation ID. The correlation ID can help find out what happened but doesn't identify what happened. Thus, to track the correlation ID for Azure AD B2C, you can do the following as stated in the below link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#echo-the-azure-ad-b2c-correlation-id

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#troubleshooting-with-application-insights